# Using GotFocus and TextChanged simultaneously - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, event-handling, windows-phone

I have an `AutoSuggestBox` which is set to handle the events **GotFocus** & **TextChanged** simultaneously. I have cleared the text from the text box in **GotFocus** event. Now the problem is that when I select any of the suggestions in `AutoSuggestBox`, after selecting it calls the **GotFocus** event handler and clears the selected text from it.

This is the `MainPage.xaml` code using the AutoSuggestBox:

```
        <AutoSuggestBox
            x:Name="auto_text_from"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            PlaceholderText="Enter Source"
            Height="auto"
            Width="280"
            GotFocus="auto_text_from_GotFocus"
            TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"/>
```

And this one is the code which I have written in `MainPage.xaml.cs` :

```
    private void auto_text_from_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        auto_text_from.Text = "";
    }


    string[] PreviouslyDefinedStringArray = new string[] {"Alwar","Ajmer","Bharatpur","Bhilwara",
        "Banswada","Jaipur","Jodhpur","Kota","Udaipur"};


    private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender,AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string myString in PreviouslyDefinedStringArray)
        {
            if (myString.ToLower().Contains(sender.Text.ToLower()) == true)
            {
                myList.Add(myString);
            }
        }
        sender.ItemsSource = myList;
    }
```

I want to use both of the event handlers. `GotFocus` for clearing the data of Text box, and `TextChanged` for showing the suggestions of writing the text in it.

Please suggest me any way to do the same.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `AutoSuggestBox` has an event to handle the selection of a suggested word, like "`SuggestionChosen`", a possibile solution is using a private flag managed between the various handlers.

Set a private field:

```
private bool _isSelectingSuggestion;
```

Link a method-handler like `OnSuggestionChosen` to the event `SuggestionChosen` and implement it like that:

```
private void OnSuggestionChosen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isSelectingSuggestion = true;
}
```

Then, in GotFocus, check the flag like this:

```
private void auto_text_from_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isSelectingSuggestion)
        e.Handled = true;
    else
        auto_text_from.Text = "";

   _isSelectingSuggestion = false;
}
```

Obviously this works only if `SuggestionChosen` is raised before `GotFocus`: when `GotFocus` begins, it proceeds like: "ok, I've got focus because a suggestion was chosen just a moment ago? If it's true, I must not clear my Text! Otherwise, I shall clear it!".

Let me know it this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

@MK87 : Yeah it worked with little bit of changes !! :)

```
    private bool _isSelectingSuggestion;

    private void OnSuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        _isSelectingSuggestion = true;
    }

    private void auto_text_from_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isSelectingSuggestion)
            auto_text_from.Text = "";

        _isSelectingSuggestion = false;
    }
```

I had to remove this line:

```
e.Handled == true;
```

as it was giving me error as `RoutedEventArgs does not contain a definition for 'Handled'`.

Thanks for your help :) :)

Comment: ... RoutedEventArgs class provide a public property, bool Handled, to set if the event has been already completely managed, or if it must be forwarded to the next event handler.