# How to stop suggestions when any of them is already picked - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, windows-phone, autosuggest

I have asked a question about [Using GotFocus and TextChanged simultaneously - Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227699/using-gotfocus-and-textchanged-simultaneously-windows-phone). In the previous question, the text from the **AutoSuggestBox** was getting cleared on choosing suggestions. So I used a `bool` type variable for checking whether a suggestion is choosen or not.

Now on selecting any suggestion, the **AutoSuggestBox** should stop showing suggestions, as I have picked what I wanted to select. So I used the same variable `TextChanged` method also.

The code for `.xaml` something like :

```
    <AutoSuggestBox
        x:Name="auto_text_from"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        PlaceholderText="Enter Source"
        Height="auto"
        Width="280"
        GotFocus="auto_text_from_GotFocus"
        TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"/>
```

And for `.xaml.cs` is

```
    private void OnSuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        _isSelectingSuggestion = true;
    }

    private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(!_isSelectingSuggestion)
        {
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string myString in stopsList)
            {
                if (sender.Text.Length > 1)
                {
                    if (myString.ToLower().Contains(sender.Text.ToLower()))
                    {
                        myList.Add(myString);
                    }
                }
            }
            sender.ItemsSource = myList;
        }
    }
```

But the task is not completed by doing so. Basically what I want is that if I select any suggestion from the list and then the **AutoSuggestBox** should stop showing suggestions.

Image showing the suggestion even after picking one: [image]

Can anyone help me out of it.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement a handler for the **SuggestionChosen** event.

**SuggestionChosen** - This event is fired when the user chooses a suggestion from the drop down. You can close the drop down in the event handler for this event and also handle the setting of the text to the value selected.

So your XAML would be like `<AutoSuggestBox Name="someBox" SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen" QuerySubmitted= .../>`

Handler Code

```
    private void AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        autoSuggestBox.Text = args.SelectedItem;
        autoSuggestBox.IsSuggestionListOpen = false;
    }
```

I would suggest you also have a look at the **QuerySubmitted** event of the AutoSuggestBox